# Console output window in DLL

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, console

I am trying to redirect the output from my DLL to an external console window for easy debugging.

I have been told about AllocConsole but I am not able to reproduce it, i.e. the console window does not appear.

My current environment is Visual Studio 2005.

I tried the following example which is gotten off the Internet,

```
AllocConsole();
HANDLE han = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
WriteConsole(han,"hello",6,new DWORD,0);
```

yet nothing happens. Can someone point me in the right direction if creating a console window via DLL is possible in the first place.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to output debug strings is via [`OutputDebugString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx), with an appropriate debugging tool listening for output strings.

Comment: That, or write it to a file or something. I agree.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams What sort of debugging tool do you recommend? I do not have the option/privilege to test out with a debugging tool as the application framework is hosted on another server, in which I am not able to perform any installation except the transfer of DLL plugins for testing. Please advice. Thanks! <br>@codeka I could write the output to the file, but then I will have to reopen the file each time there is a change and I am expecting live changes every second.

Answer (score 2):

Once loaded, there is nothing special about DLLs, so there is no way that allocating consoles would be any different for a DLL than for the EXE that originally loaded it.

Having said that, a process can be associated with only one console at a time, so if there is already a console attached to the process, then allocating a new one is not going to do anything (I assume you're checking the return value of [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx)? What does it return? What does `GetLastError` return?)

There are some other possibilities. For example, if your DLL is loaded into a service, then the service will (likely) be running under a different window station to the currently logged-in user so if you create a console window, you won't be able to see it.